# Access class decorator argument using reflect-metadata

Tags: typescript, reflection, reflect-metadata

Consider a class decorator with one argument:

```
@TableName("Orders")
export class Order {
 // ...
}
```

And the decorator defined as:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const classDecoratorKey = Symbol.for("custom:TableName");

export function TableName(tableName: string): ClassDecorator {
  return (constructor: Function) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(classDecoratorKey, tableName, constructor);
  }
}

export function getTableName(target: any): string {
  return Reflect.getMetadata(classDecoratorKey, target.constructor, "class") || "";
}
```

I expect now to get the @TableName value "Orders". How can I retrieve the class decorator's argument value?

```
let order = new Order();
getTableName(order); // "" but expected "Orders"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me

```
export function TableName(tableName: string): ClassDecorator {
  return (constructor: Function) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(classDecoratorKey, tableName, constructor.prototype);
  };
}

export function getTableName(target: any): string {
  return Reflect.getMetadata(classDecoratorKey, target) || '';
}
```